# Real and complex vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a real finite-dimensional vector space and let $V_\mathbb{C}=V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ be its complexification. Now let $W\subset V_\mathbb{C}$ be a complex subspace.

Clearly, $W$ need not to be generated by vectors with real coordinates (for example, the line generated by $(1,i)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$). But, is it always possible to express $W$ as the direct sum of two vector spaces each of one generated by real vectors?

For example, $W=\langle(1,i)\rangle_\mathbb{C}$ as before can be seen as the graph of the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $T(x)=ix$.

In general, given a complex subspace of $W$ of $V_\mathbb{C}$, is it always possible to find a decomposition $V_\mathbb{C}=E\oplus F$ such that each of these vector spaces is generated by real vectors and we can identify $W$ with the graph of a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $T:E\to F$?

Thanks!